# Ionic Capacitor: how to see console when running on android emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-emulator, capacitor

I am new to ionic and I want to run my app on an android emulator with hot reload and get access to the console. I use this command (i'm using capacitor):
`ionic capacitor run android`
but once the app is deployed the terminal is terminated and i don't get access to the console[image: as you can see here]
so how can i see whatever is printed in the console?
Thanks for your help
P.S: I'm using VS Code, I don't know if running it in Android Studio would solve this but I don't get to do it cuz there seems the project is not detected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Desktop Chrome you can open `chrome://inspect/#devices` url and your device will appear there and all the debuggable apps that are opened at the moment.
Pick your app and you'll see the logs.

Comment: thanks that was helpful, what about hot reload ? is it supported ?

Comment: Yeah, use —livereload param https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/livereload

Answer (score 1):

For firefox, enter in url bar:

`about:debugging`

Then you'll be able to connect via usb, or enter device host:port.

See https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/remote_debugging/firefox_for_android/index.html